# SQL Query to generate a column condition where it doesn't necessarily need to be empty nor filled

Tags: android, mysql, sql

I'm having a problem with my sql query. It's more of a parent and child table. Since the user can be either parent or child. I made a table with 4 columns.

1st column is the user's username
2nd column is the user's password
3rd column is the user type (parent or child)
4th column is the parent username's column(when the user is a child).

Now, when a user registers as parent, he/she doesn't necessarily have the 4th column filled. But when the user registers as child, he/she has to have it filled. Can anyone help?

Take note, this has to be only 1 table.

Here is my SQL Query:

```
CREATE TABLE user (uname text primary key not null, password text not null, usertype text not null, parent text);
```

Comment: It seems no problem with your query. Fill the 4th field by null when insert parent

Comment: DDL like CREATE is just for defining what a table can accept, you will need to filter the user and determine if the field is required or not using  DML or some client side verification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is 100% working by adding this check constraints as shown below.

```
ALTER TABLE user ADD CONSTRAINT
ck_CheckParents CHECK 
(
    ((usertype='parent') and (parent is null)) or 
    ((usertype='child') and (parent is not null ))
)
GO
```

If you need something to be there in `parent` column when user type is 'Parent', then simply remove one condition.

```
ALTER TABLE user ADD CONSTRAINT
ck_CheckParents CHECK  
    ((usertype='child') and (parent is not null ))
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

From design perspective it would be better to have two separated columns for the parent and the child, out of which one and only one would have to be filled. Separating different concerns in different field will probably make the logic simpler when querying the table.

You can use a constraint check to control that the data you put in the table matches the rule.

```
ALTER TABLE user 
    ADD CONSTRAINT ck_CheckParents
CHECK  
    ( child is null and parent is not null )
     or ( child is not null and parent is null )
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now, when a user registers as parent, he/she doesn't necessarily have the 4th column filled. But when the user registers as child, he/she has to have it filled.

Note that this descriptions allows a "parent" to have a parent.

MySQL doesn't give many options for this.  You can express this logic using a "check constraint":

```
alter users add constraint ck_users_parent
    check ( not (usertype = 'child' and parent is null) );
```

Unfortunately, MySQL does not implement "check" constraints, so the logic doesn't do anything.  You could implement the logic using a trigger, but that seems like overkill.

My recommendation?  Remove the user type column.  Let the data speak for itself.  You have a hierarchical structure, so you can query that to get the "type" of the user.